# How to add moving buttons and automatic move for several seconds for pictures?

Tags: html, button, slide

I would like to add the left and right button for move to last or next picture + move image automatically for several seconds. I saw some tutorials but I don´t know how to add code to this code with buttons at the bottom side

buttons on the left and right sides

[image: buttons on left and right sides]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slidershow middle">

      <div class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4">
        <div class="slide s1">
          <img src="img/d1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/d2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/d3.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="img/d4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navigation">
        <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r4" class="bar"></label>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use some like [Owl Carousel 2](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2)

If you want to use the default navigation styles, you will also need to include owl.theme.default.css.

Put the script at the bottom of your markup right after jQuery:

```
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Usage
Wrap your items (div, a, img, span, li etc.) with a container element (div, ul etc.). Only the class owl-carousel is mandatory to apply proper styles:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: The owl-theme class is optional, but without it, you will need to style navigation features on your own.

Call the plugin function and your carousel is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});
```